# How to prevent multiple login windows?

Tags: macos, password, login, macbook-pro, login-screen

Whenever my rMBP wakes up from sleep, it shows a log in page with my user name. The page has a metallic gray background. After I enter my password, another page opens up with my wallpaper along with my user name again, and I have to enter the password one more time.

Output of `diskutil list` for /dev/disk0 is:

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

How do I disable multiple login windows each asking for a password when my laptop starts or wakes up from sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else tried bmike's method but didn't fix multiple logins, try the following :

1. System Preferences
2. Security and Privacy
3. Unlock the settings using the lock button (buttom left)
4. Advanced
5. Disable "Log out after ## minutes of inactivity" option

Now you should only get one login screen after a screen saver or waking up, rather than logging you out and having to enter the password twice.

What I deduced from this is that it logs you out, and you have to enter the password to log in again. Then the lock to the desktop shows up, where you have to enter the password again to access the main desktop. Weird, if anyone knows another way to fix this please do reply.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I'll file a bug if I can reproduce this. Seems like the OS is resuming your exact state when that is total overkill...

Answer (score 2):

Disable File Vault if you don't want this two step log in process. You can be sure FileVault is off by seeing the following from terminal:

```
Mac:~ me$ diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Alternatively, you could disable and re-enable the File Vault encryption and watch for the prompt where it asks if the OS user should be permitted to unlock the drive with the user's password.

If you select yes from that, the user will show up on the first login screen and both unlock the FileVault protected volume and log in with the same credentials.

Comment: File Vault is already disabled for me. However, when I go to Security and Privacy, then click advanced, there is an option that says "Log out after ## minutes of inactivity" .. would this be the problem ?? Kind of doubt it though.

Comment: Wow - that's odd. What does `diskutil list` show if you type that in the terminal. This clearly isn't the normal behavior - so it might take a bit to suss out what has gotten messed up. I wonder what a newly created admin user does when you let it sleep with only that user logged in. Also - you might add the OS level of your Mac to the question in case that helps...

Comment: Also - you might want to try turning on File Vault to see if that assists in setting the keys that normally prevent this sort of two-step authentication dance.

Comment: This what shows when I enter that code in Terminal : /dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

Comment: Perfect. You could check that the same info is shown when you boot to the recovery HD and run terminal there, but it's looking like my FileVault guess isn't the cause of your glitch.

Comment: Soooo what now ? I tried disabling the "Log out after ## minutes of inactivity" option, maybe that is the problem ?